# Adding tooltip in javascript graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I really need help! Please..
I need to add tooltip to this graph: http://jsfiddle.net/dvqFj/1/
Any idea how I can do it? Or do you know any similar example in D3.js
I have tried the following without no sucess:

```
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 12px;
  padding: 8px;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background: #ddd;
  border: solid 1px #aaa;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}


     var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 1e-6)

function mouseover() {
  div.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 1);
}

function mousemove() {
  div
      .text(d3.event.pageX + ", " + d3.event.pageY)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 34) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 12) + "px");
}

function mouseout() {
  div.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 1e-6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether this is an option for you, but one possibility is to use a title element, rather than implementing your own tooltip. This has the advantage of being standard and simple, at the expense of reducing possible customisation.

http://jsfiddle.net/ezUex/

```
browser.append("path")
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", function (d) {
        return area(d.values);
    })
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.name);
    })
    .append("title").text(function(d){ return d.name; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it! The `mouseover` functions just needed to be attached to your path elements:

```
browser.append("path")
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", function (d) { return area(d.values); })
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.name); })
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseout",  mouseout);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dvqFj/5/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. but I need to show the value of x and y of the axis of the graph not the page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697876/mousemove-callback-on-a-path-element-in-d3js/16698594#16698594